# Using Deriv package for derivative wrt vector

Tags: r, autodiff

I am exploring autodiff, and I would like to use `Deriv` for computing a derivative of a function wrt to a vector. I write

```
library(numDeriv)
library(Deriv)
h = function(x) c(1,2)%*%x
grad(h,c(1,2)) #ok
#[1] 1 2
dh=Deriv(h,x='x')
#Error in c(1, 2) %*% 1 : non-conformable arguments
dh(c(1,2))
```

Does anyone have a good way to do this?

From `help(Deriv)`, it seems like one should be able to let the argument be a vector

> here is a side effect with vector length. E.g. in Deriv(~a+b*x, c("a",
> "b")) the result is c(a = 1, b = x). To avoid the difference in
> lengths of a and b components (when x is a vector), one can use an
> optional parameter combine Deriv(~a+b*x, c("a", "b"), combine="cbind")
> which gives cbind(a = 1, b = x) producing a two column matrix which is
> probably the desired result here.

I would like to avoid making each of the vector components a different argument to the function.

For example `numDeriv` above lets us easily take a derivative wrt vector `x`

Comment: The problem isn't with Deriv its that you can't pass a single numeric vector to matrix multiplication. i.e. h(1) will give you the error you see but h(c(1,4)) will not.

Comment: would the `madness` package be useful to you ... ?

Comment: @BenBolker - Thank you - I have looked into it a bit, but I wanted to check first whether `Deriv` supports autodiff wrt a vector, and if I was just making a mistake.  Maybe I will go in that direction

Comment: @HenryHolm thanks - would you be able to provide an example using Deriv?

Answer (score 2):

This is an answer; The to packages handles multiple dimensions differently.

```r
library(numDeriv)
library(Deriv)
h = function(x,y) c(1,2) %*% c(x,y)
grad(\(x) h(x[1], x[2]),c(1,2))
dh = Deriv(h)
dh(c(1,2))
```

Comment: thanks - I had wanted to avoid making the components separate args because then if I have a 100 dimensional vector it would require 100 inputs

Comment: maybe I am missing something about passing though args .. eg is there like a `...` operator I can use to avoid this..

Comment: still it seems like it would be ideal if Deriv just could take a vector argument

Comment: What do you mean by many inputs? Multiple dimensions or multiple points? because you could make a function `base::Vectorize`, and thus make it take multiple points of a certain dimension.

Comment: `h = function(x,y)` has 2 inputs whereas `h = function(x)` has one

Comment: Well, put up an example of multiple argument function you want to differentiate...

Comment: I wanted to stay with `h = function(x) c(1,2)%*%x` where `x` is a vector rather than  `h = function(x,y) c(1,2)%*%c(x,y)` where `x,y` are scalars.

Comment: Maybe the `Vectorize` function you mention might allow me to avoid this though..

Comment: So if I had function `h=function(x) 1:1000%*%x` how would I use the method above

Comment: I cannot figure that out. Might be impossible. Sorry

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using not `Deriv` but `madness,` a really neat package.

We basically create an object that is the thing we would like to take the derivative with respect to (in this case `x`), and then as we apply functions to that object, the derivatives are collected.

We get the evaluated derivative using this function, as we do with `grad` in `numDeriv`.

```
library(madness)

h = function(x){t(x)%*%matrix(c(2,1),nrow=2,ncol=1)}
x=matrix(c(1,1),nrow=2,ncol=1)

gd=function(h,x){
x=madness(val=x)
z=h(x)
attr(z,"dvdx")
}
gd(h,x)
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    2    1
```

Answer (score 1):

This feels really kludgy:

```
library(Deriv)

sz <- 100
f.vec <- function(x) 1:sz%*%x
xs <- paste0("x", 1:sz, collapse = ",")
h <- eval(parse(text = paste0("h <- function(", xs, ") f.vec(c(", xs, "))")))
dh <- Deriv(h)
dh(1:sz)
#>   x1   x2   x3   x4   x5   x6   x7   x8   x9  x10  x11  x12  x13  x14  x15  x16 
#>    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16 
#>  x17  x18  x19  x20  x21  x22  x23  x24  x25  x26  x27  x28  x29  x30  x31  x32 
#>   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   24   25   26   27   28   29   30   31   32 
#>  x33  x34  x35  x36  x37  x38  x39  x40  x41  x42  x43  x44  x45  x46  x47  x48 
#>   33   34   35   36   37   38   39   40   41   42   43   44   45   46   47   48 
#>  x49  x50  x51  x52  x53  x54  x55  x56  x57  x58  x59  x60  x61  x62  x63  x64 
#>   49   50   51   52   53   54   55   56   57   58   59   60   61   62   63   64 
#>  x65  x66  x67  x68  x69  x70  x71  x72  x73  x74  x75  x76  x77  x78  x79  x80 
#>   65   66   67   68   69   70   71   72   73   74   75   76   77   78   79   80 
#>  x81  x82  x83  x84  x85  x86  x87  x88  x89  x90  x91  x92  x93  x94  x95  x96 
#>   81   82   83   84   85   86   87   88   89   90   91   92   93   94   95   96 
#>  x97  x98  x99 x100 
#>   97   98   99  100
```

The evaluation time for `Deriv` seems to increase roughly quadratically with the number of parameters:

```
varDeriv <- function(sz) {
  system.time({
    f.vec <- function(x) 1:sz%*%x
    xs <- paste0("x", 1:sz, collapse = ",")
    h <- eval(parse(text = paste0("h <- function(", xs, ") f.vec(c(", xs, "))")))
    dh <- Deriv(h)
    dh(1:sz)
  })
}

Vectorize(varDeriv)(seq(100, 500, by = 100))
#>             [,1]  [,2]  [,3]   [,4]   [,5]
#> user.self  0.712 2.700 6.498 11.782 20.854
#> sys.self   0.015 0.011 0.020  0.055  0.068
#> elapsed    0.727 2.710 6.518 11.839 20.922
#> user.child 0.000 0.000 0.000  0.000  0.000
#> sys.child  0.000 0.000 0.000  0.000  0.000
```