# Compute partial derivatives with `madness`

Tags: r, derivative, autodiff

The `madness` packages, as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69876390/using-deriv-package-for-derivative-wrt-vector/69876456?noredirect=1#comment123519149_69876456), is nice for autodiff in R.

I would like to compute now a derivative wrt x of a derivative wrt y.

$\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\frac{\partial}{\partial y}xy$

[image]

how can this be done using `madness`?

update: actually here I guess it factors.. maybe this will be ok by just multiplying the two derivatives?  Maybe this will only be difficult if x is a function of y.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a way using the `numderiv` function in `madness`:

```
library(madness)

dxdy <- function(x, y, f) {
  dy <- function(x, y) {
    dvdx(f(x, y))
  }
  
  numderiv(dy, x, y = y)
}

x <- matrix(1:3, nrow = 1)
y <- matrix(3:1, ncol = 1)
# identity matrix, as expected
dvdx(dxdy(madness(x), madness(y), function(x, y) x%*%y))
#>      [,1] [,2] [,3]
#> [1,]    1    0    0
#> [2,]    0    1    0
#> [3,]    0    0    1
x <- matrix(2, ncol = 1)
y <- matrix(3, ncol = 1)
dvdx(dxdy(madness(x), madness(y), function(x, y) y^x))
#>          [,1]
#> [1,] 9.591674
# compare to analytical solution
y^(x-1)*(x*log(y) + 1)
#>          [,1]
#> [1,] 9.591674
x <- matrix(1:3, ncol = 1)
y <- matrix(3:1, ncol = 1)
dvdx(dxdy(madness(x), madness(y), function(x, y) sum(y^x)))
#>          [,1]     [,2] [,3]
#> [1,] 2.098612 0.000000    0
#> [2,] 0.000000 4.772589    0
#> [3,] 0.000000 0.000000    1
# compare to analytical solution
y^(x-1)*(x*log(y) + 1)
#>          [,1]
#> [1,] 2.098612
#> [2,] 4.772589
#> [3,] 1.000000
x <- matrix(1:3, ncol = 1)
y <- matrix(3:1, ncol = 1)
dvdx(dxdy(madness(x), madness(y), function(x, y) sum(sin(x*y))))
#>           [,1]     [,2]      [,3]
#> [1,] -1.413352 0.000000  0.000000
#> [2,]  0.000000 2.373566  0.000000
#> [3,]  0.000000 0.000000 -1.413353
# compare to analytical solution
cos(x*y) - x*y*sin(x*y)
#>           [,1]
#> [1,] -1.413353
#> [2,]  2.373566
#> [3,] -1.413353
```

Note that the `madness` derivatives are the partials of each `x` (columns) with respect to the `y` partials of each `xy` (rows).

Comment: Thank you - this does answer the question, so I am accepting.  I had been hoping to use however the autodiff functionality rather than the numerical derivative (I think madness provides both).

Comment: Understood. That's where I started, but I'm pretty convinced now that `madness` can't do that. See this question for working with Hessians symbolically in case it can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20297711/r-hessian-matrix